# I am trying to connect my Google Cloud VPC to a secure network via a VPN

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, point-to-site-vpn

I am trying to connect my Google Cloud VPC to a secure network via a VPN.

I am unable to connect and log shows the following:

```
D  generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ] 
D  no matching peer config found 
D  looking for peer configs matching YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY[%any]...XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[192.168.0.2] 
D  parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) AUTH SA TSi TSr ] 
D  received packet: from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[4500] to YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY[4500] (204 bytes) 
D  sending packet: from YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY[500] to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[500] (440 bytes) 
D  generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(MULT_AUTH) ] 
D  remote host is behind NAT 
I  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is initiating an IKE_SA
```

What am I missing? The peer network gateway IP is configured as XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and my Google Cloud IP is YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY.

The steps to create the VPN followed are mentioned in the following link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns#creating_a_gateway_and_a_tunnel_for_an_auto_mode_vpc_network_using_only_the_gateway_subnet

What could be wrong?

All the configuration are as per the settings mentioned in the document: https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithFortinetFortiGate300C.pdf

Comment: You'll need to post your Fortigate configuration (removing IPs, PSKs, domain names, etc) so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a clone of this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45698093/1308883) question. According to the comments in there, this error was caused because, at the time, Cloud VPN did not support NAT Traversal.

Currently, [NAT-T is supported](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/support/troubleshooting#gateways_behind_nat) given the right configuration.